# Java EE application with too many webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, osgi

I'm working with a **Java EE** application that exposes more than 150 webservices contracts with multiple operations each.

I think this is the cause for a long publishing time and OutOfMemory erros when updating the application in the container.

*I would like to know way to modify this application architecture in order to support this multiples webservices.*

I'm working with the **Java EE 5** spec.

**Separating it in multiple war files is a good approach?**

**Maybe OSGi. Is it possible to use `OSGi` on `WAS 7` ? Is it a good solution?**

---

**ADDED**

Maybe expanding **JVM's** memory can solve the problem for a time, but there are other concerns that memory won't help.

This application is accessed by multiple application. Updating one webservice impact all the clients that use another webservice. I would like insights about how to decouple this **EAR**.

Comment: your container will run in the same JVM, so I think what you really need is a machine with more memory and a bigger JVM heap

Comment: What is your current max heap size? Are you using build in web service engine or some third party?

Comment: Webservices are JAX-WS 2.1. I don't have information about the server memory properties, but I would like to know some insights about the application architecture itself. Adding memory may solve the problem for a time, but as the app increases, the problem happens again.

Comment: "...OutOfMemory erros when updating the application in the container...".Do you update the application using hot deploy?If so, may be  you need restart the server, and to put a load-balancer on front to maintain availability.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you start your JVM with the flag to unload classes every update will add the same amount of classes on top. This will cause you an OOM or more specific a PermSpace issue. Unless you start your server with the right settings, lot's of Memory (you're running a JEE app right?) and right sizing for PermSpace etc.. you will always run into this. 
The OSGi part won't solve it either. 
*And* this will always dependent on the JVM itself, the Oracle JVM does support unloading of Classes, while starting with 8 it doesn't contain a PermSpace any longer. Though at that point you'll have to watch the stack :)